# device webKitView not loading local images but simulator load the images

Tags: swift, webkit

I have a html file located locally in the Library directory of the device and some images in the same directory. so when I open the webkitview in a simulator it loads the images perfectly but when I use a device the html page is loaded but the images are not loaded.this is my html :

```
<html><head><script src='./test.js'></script></head><body><img src='./sample_attachment.jpg' alt='Girl in a jacket' /><body><html>
```

and this is how I load the web view:

```
            webView.loadFileURL(path, allowingReadAccessTo: path)
```

I have also enabled the Allow Arbitrary Loads in info.plist. 
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution it can help anyone of you: 
the first path in webView.loadFileURL(firstPath, allowingReadAccessTo: secondPath) is the path to the html file and the second path is the path to resources that you are allowed to open, the problem I was putting the same path that's why only the html page is loaded (I don't know why the simulator load the ressources correctly) but when I put the path to the directory in the second path it can access all the resources and load them perfectly.